# Calibrate for an inaccurate 50 ohm load in a DIY Vector Network Analyser (VNA) based on a VSWR RF bridge

Tags: rf, antenna, load, vna

I have built a "DIY VNA" using a frequency generator, an SDR receiver, a RF Reflection Bridge and a 50 ohm load. This is used to measure "VSWR values" of antennas to see what frequencies they are matched to.
My reference for the build is https://medium.com/home-wireless/testing-antennas-with-the-limesdr-mini-98b59b99c8b9

I am not sure how accurate the results are. I have some doubt in the results. I have measured the 50 ohm load that I have with a multi meter and it shows 52 ohm rather than 50 ohm. Is this something that will have an effect on the power loss measurements vs base values that I am doing? Does this affect where the antenna will have its measured maximum power loss vs the true value?

Can I compensate for this error or calibrate the results to be true while using the 52 ohm value that I have? Can I estimate the error on frequency based on the error in the load resistance?

Comment: There are plenty of formulas online that explain this. What particular area are you struggling with that isn't explained by googling? For instance, have you calculated what the VSWR is when terminating in 52 ohms instead of 50 ohms? Have you estimated the amount of power reflected? Have you not drawn any conclusions from the wealth of information available online?

Comment: For what you're trying to do, I don't think the difference between a 50 ohm load and a 52 ohm load will be measurable.  And if it is, I doubt it will have any noticeable effect on your antenna's performance.

Comment: If the 50Ω is really 52Ω (use a calibrated meter), then [add](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-paralresist.htm) 1300Ω in parallel. Careful to minimize parasitics, of course.